# Scroll Wheel not registering all scrolls

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

Im having an issue with my mouse. Its a Logitech G502 Lightspeed wireless mouse that works perfectly on windows.

But whenever I'm on Ubuntu, the scroll wheel does yanky shit. When I'm scrolling through a webpage on firefox in one direction and then stop and scroll in the opposite direction, the first scroll almost always gets skipped and doesnt scroll the page. I'm also 99 % sure that it sometimes registers a scroll action twice, but I can't reliably reproduce it like I can reproduce the skipped scrolls stuff.

I ran `xev` to see if the scrolls get registered by it and it also shows this problem (direction switching leads to the first scroll not being registered at all). Interestingly, the file explorer nautilus does not skip scrolls, which indicates to me that its not a system wide issue (but isn't xev very low level? if so, why doesn't it work?)

While searching for a solution, I found some people recommending `imwheel`, but for me it did not change the skipped scroll actions, it just allowed me to make all registered scroll actions skip more lines, but that isn't my problem here, skipped inputs just feel like shit.

I don't know if that's just being nitpicky, but this issue is driving me crazy and makes me just not want to use ubuntu because it annoys me so much.
I hope somebody has an idea on what I could do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the problem persist after disabling `general.smoothScroll` in `about:config`? `xev` is not completely low-level, to go lower you can use `evtest`